# What does the if( $n ) do in the code below?

Tags: perl

So I'm new to Perl. I know the code below is suppose to generate full binary trees. But what does the if ($n) mean. Does it check if the variable $n is null?

```
sub tree {
  my ($n) = @_;
  my @result = ();
  if ( $n ) {
    for $right_count ( 0 .. $n-1 ) {
      for $right ( tree( $right_count ) ) {
        for $left ( tree( ($n-1) - $right_count ) ) {
          push @result, "1$left$right";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    push @result, "0";
  }
  return @result;
}
foreach $tree ( tree($_) ) {
  print $tree;
}
```

Comment: See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood and https://www.perlmonks.org/?node=what%20is%20true%20and%20false%20in%20Perl%3F - it checks whether `$n` contains a true value. In your case, it checks whether `$n` is 0 or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code `if ($n)` *almost* checks if $n is null.

In Perl, there is no concept of "null". A variable is either `defined` or not. You can check that with `if (defined($n))`.

`if ($n)` really checks whether `$n` is *truthy*. The exact details are documented in the [perlsyn](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood) page.

Note that *similar* rules exist for many programming languages, like C, JavaScript, PHP, Python, Ruby. These languages all define what they consider "truthy", but they don't agree with each other.

Comment: In my example above why would $n ever be not defined? Or in other words when would if($n) return false?

Comment: @abc Please read the linked pages. They explain what is considered false in Perl. In your case, it's `0` that is considered a false value.

Comment: @abc - `$n` would be falsey if you called `tree()` (`$n` is undefined), `tree('')` (an empty string), `tree(0)` (numeric zero), or `tree('0')` (the string `0` - but `00` is truthy! This case depends on the exact string being `0`, not just having a numeric value of 0.).

Comment: I find this answer a little confusing. What matters is that the `if` returns true if and only if `$n` is positive when interpreted as a number, that is to say, if and only if the `for` loop will run, which is the intention, as the `else` is there to provide behavior for the cases in which it won't run.